# Wordpress: How to Create widget area in Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, custom-widgets

I want to create a new placeholder / area for widgets in Wordpress admin panel.

Please have a look in screenshot i provided below for better understanding.
[image]

As you see there are total 3 place holders for widgets. I want to add more custom placeholders like 4th, 5th..

Also I want to add the placeholder in my theme to display widgets.

For example i created new 4th place holder in admin panel. And there are total 2 widgets in that placeholder.  And i want to display all of widgets of 4th placeholder in them with its order.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/ - and google is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widget areas can be added by using the [`register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'so16750248_register_sidebar' );
function so16750248_register_sidebar(){
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Another Sidebar' ),
        'id' => 'another-sidebar',
        'description' => __( 'Some widgets here.', 'my_textdomain' ),
        'before_title' => '<h1>',
        'after_title' => '</h1>'
    ) );
}
```

To call the widget area in a template, use [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar):

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'another-sidebar' );
```